# How to find a permalink/share-link to an Instagram post?

Tags: links, instagram, url

Open Instagram using a desktop browser.

Scroll down in your feed to find a post.

How do you find the permalink (or share-link, sharelink, etc.) that can be copied and pasted into other applications?

This is not a request to find a link to someone's profile on Instagram.

Comment: The Instagram help has a specific help article that answers this -> [How do I get a link (URL) to a photo or video on Instagram?](https://help.instagram.com/372819389498306/?helpref=uf_share)

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question, because Instagram hid it underneath the "dot-dot-dot" menu, making it non-obvious to users of normal web apps that put the share (a link) button up front and center where it is difficult to miss:

Navigate to your feed, and scroll down until you see a post. Look to the right and find the "..." menu. e.g.:
[image]

Click on the "..." button, and click on the **Copy Link** button:

[image]

Now you have the link.

Example:

https://www.instagram.com/tv/CcpuPK1DWmt/?utm_source=ig_web_button_share_sheet